# Hibernate Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.XXX.XXX.XXX.Coordinate.id to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am new to Hibernate and got stuck on a problem. I am not able to save a CustomObject which contains a List< List< Coordinate>> . I am using MySQL with SpingBoot.

CustomOjbect:

```
@Entity
public class CustomOjbect implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4288223602669270676L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "img")
    private String img;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Feet feet;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=Coordinate.class)
    private List<List<Coordinate>> coordinates = null;
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    //Other getter and setters here...
}
```

Coordinate:

```
@Entity
public class Coordinate implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7288778461661904967L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "y")
    private Float y;
    @Column(name = "x")
    private Float x;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    //Getter and setters here...
}
```

Feet:

```
@Entity
public class Feet implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8438970667123556624L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "height")
    private Integer height;

    @Column(name = "width")
    private Integer width;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    //Getter and setters here
}
```

It used to work fine when I do List< Coordinate> instead of List< < List< Coordinate>>, but I had to change it as the object sent from client side changed to array of array of objects.

How do I fix this?

The error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer
>   field com.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.Coordinate.id to
>   java.util.ArrayList   at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_111]   at
>   org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:225)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4675)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4376)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:510)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:99)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:765)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:398)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:431)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]

In controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/saveCustomObjects", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveImageDetails(@RequestBody CustomObject customObject) {
        customObjectRepository.save(customObject);
        return "Saved successfully";
    }
```

**Edit**:

**Please ask me if you need to know anything.**

Comment: Why just not map object received from client to your valid entity model?

Comment: @MGorgon How do I do that? I think I am doing that.

Comment: I suppose you have some kind of DTO received from client?

Comment: @MGorgon Please check I have added my controller where I do the save.

Comment: Ok. please read about DTO. There should be additional layer of separation - so you'll need to introduce another model layer (DTO layer). Then your transport (request/response) model won't be directly coupled with persistence model.

Comment: @MGorgon Then why did it work with List<Coordinate>? Also can you please add a link to read.

Comment: Because List of entities is valid jpa relation. List of lists isn't. So you need to separate your presentation model from persistence model and introduce mapping between them.

Comment: Ok thank you, so I think I need to change the json format from the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who face this problem.

As MGorgon pointed  out in the comments `List` of entities `List< Object>` is a **valid jpa relation** whereas `List` of `List` `List< List< Object>>` **isn't a valid jpa relation**.

So to fix this problem I changed the json format sent from the client.

JSON format before:

```
{
  "coordinates": [
    [
      {
      },
      {
      }
    [
      {
      },
      {
      },
      {
      },
      {
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

JSON format after changing:

```
{
  "coordinates": [
    {
      "area": [
        {
        },
        {
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "area": [
        {
        },
        {
        },
        {
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: I have eliminated some properties in the json to reduce code.

Hope it will help someone.